# Applying sample() to a list of data frames

Tags: r

I am doing a project where I am trying to randomly select individual studies from a groups of related studies. I have succeeded an dividing a master data file in data frames of related studies.

```
##Subset by independent study, determined by integer assignment in column 18
tmp <- split(DATAFILE, DATAFILE$V18)
lapply(1:length(tmp), 
       function(x) assign(paste("study.", x, sep = ""), 
                          tmp[[x]], envir = .GlobalEnv))
```

Now I want to take a randow row from each one of those data frames, and I can't get it to work.
I've tried a for loop, where it tells me "could not find function i":

```
random <-NULL
   for (i in tmp){
   i(sample(nrow(i)), 1,)
   random<-rbind(random,i)
   print(df)
}
```

I'd like to put a random sample of 1 row from each data frame into a new data frame, so I tried sapply

```
sapply(df.list, function(x) sample(nrow(i), 1,))
```

Which doesn't work either.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Try `data[sample(nrow(data), n), ]` to sample the rows.

Answer (score 0):

It is much better to keep your data in a list rather than assigning a bunch of objects to your workspace. Your sapply is close, but that will only give you the indices of the random rows you want from each data set in the list.

Next you need to select the sampled row from each data set in the list, so one was is to use `lapply` to return a list of rows, and bind them all together:

```
datl <- split(mtcars, f = mtcars$gear)

idx <- sapply(datl, function(x) sample(nrow(x), 1))

do.call(rbind, lapply(1:3, function(x) datl[[x]][idx[x], ]))

                   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Chrysler Imperial 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
Honda Civic       30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
Ferrari Dino      19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
```